# Form of proof of professional experience for Spanish Digial Nomad visa

Tags: spain, digital-nomads

I am a U.S. citizen working on my documentation to apply for the Spanish Digital Nomad visa. I meet all the described requirements in terms of income, contract, health care, etc... but I don't have a university degree. The documentation I have seen indicates that I can use proof of employment of 3 or more years in my field instead, but it is vague on the form that must take.

- Is a confirmation of employment letter from a past employer sufficient?
- Does this sort of thing need to be apostilled? How does that work? I understand how government documents are apostilled by the state, but private parties? Do I get a local notarization and then engage an apostille service?

I would love to hear others experience.

Comment: From where are you applying?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I am a US citizen. I am physically in Europe so I will likely be applying in Spain. Wasn't sure in which sense you meant.

Comment: In which country are you going to physically lodge your application? The US? The UK? A EU country? You can't apply for a visa in the country itself

Comment: No that doesn't seem to be the case for the new Digital Nomad visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this sort of thing need to be apostilled?

Apostilles/legalisations are only for documents issued by governments themselves (like, a birth certificate) you can't apostille a private person's document.

The city of Barcelona [states](https://www.barcelona.cat/internationalwelcome/en/legalisation-and-translation-documents) :

> For some formalities required to live in Barcelona, especially related to immigration, you will have to provide documents issued by public authorities in your country of origin.

> Is a confirmation of employment letter from a past employer sufficient?

It is also [stated](https://www.barcelona.cat/internationalwelcome/en/residency-digital-nomads-visa-and-permit)

> If you do not have that qualification, a letter of experience signed by your current or previous employer that certifies professional experience of at least 3 years for analogous functions to those you would perform in the post.

[Indeed](https://www.barcelona.cat/internationalwelcome/en/residency-digital-nomads-visa-and-permit) has a walkthrough on what is a letter of experience, but a end of contract letter stating how mucb time you passed in that company should work

Don't forget you also need to translate it with a registered translator like all documents